# What is the medical term for a scab?

Tags: scab

Google will not help get me to a definitive answer based on my search terms. What is the proper medical term for the crust that forms when blood coagulates? Also, is it different for different parts of the body or internal vs. external?

Comment: Ha was just writing this as you updated that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll likely get a response that "eschar" means "scab".  ***This is incorrect.***

---

### Understanding Why the Term "Eschar" is Incorrect

What differentiates this term? Factors such as the dermal layer involved *(location)* and wound type it is associated with.  "Eschar" is a medical term that describes necrotic (dead) tissue found *within* a full-thickness wound.

---

**"Sanguineous Crust"** would be a precise medical term for "scab".

Comment: Is "Sanguineous Crust" still in active use in the medical community? I found search hits for that term in references to old medical terms and in an excerpt from a medical text published in 1845.

Comment: Very typically it is simply written by as "crust" or "scab".  As most of these words are of greek / latin origin it is very common that you'll see it referenced as an "old" medical term.  Simply put in a patients chart you would still very commonly see "scab", however "Sanguineous Crust" is the most precise term.

Comment: Is this for a class - or what is the exact need for this information?  In a practical sense the term scab is 1. short (we love short words, abbreviations lol) 2. widely understood. Adding "Sanguineous" to the word makes this overly complex.  As reimbursement is decided by people much less versed in medical terminology, you'd actually be doing them a disservice.  They will not likely know what the long overly complex term "Sanguineous Crust" means

Comment: I asked this same question in med school because it sounds so colloquial.  Sanguinous crust is correct.  Or just crust.  But internal doesn't make as much sense, so I'm not sure what you're defining as scab?

Comment: @DoctorWhom - I believe he / she (see I'm learning lol) is referring to an internal "wound" -- which is not a "scab" as it is not exposed to the air.  What do you write in your documentation?  I've personally never used or seen the term "sanguineous crust" in any documentation.  I don't see the need......

Comment: @DoctorWhom - I have a question for you, I'm starting a new thread -- could never make sense of this...

Comment: Hey Mike, if you want to you can join us [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65231/the-state-of-health). We want to reshape Health.SE and are discussing how to do that in this chat room. It'd be great to see you hop in, your opinion is greatly valued!

Comment: Is this like a delayed chat-room?  I actually was going to reply to the thread you created but wanted to put some thought into it so wasn't rushing it

Comment: @Mike-DHSc  I almost never have seen it either, even rotating with derm.  Crusting sometimes, scabbing sometimes.  I always cringe when documenting it because writing "sanguinous crust" feels excessively technical and "scab" feels too colloquial!

Comment: @Mike-DHSc Ah yes *wound* is the correct term for the tissue that is damaged/healing at the site of injury (or intentional like in surgery). On the inside the same process of coagulated blood might be called a hematoma, collection of coagulated blood;  It happens a little differently inside but is the same general coagulation process.